# How to prove that the cross product is associative directly?

Tags: hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories, quantum-groups

The following result is proved using diagrams in Lemma 14.2 on page 85 in the book [a quantum groups primer](https://books.google.co.il/books/about/A_Quantum_Groups_Primer.html?id=NY6ikD9hDs0C&redir_esc=y) by S. Majid.

Let $B, C$ be two algebras in a braided monoidal category. Then the braided tensor product algebra $B \underline{\otimes} C$ has the structure of an algebra in the category.

My question is: how to prove this lemma directly? My solution: let $b,b',b'' \in B$ and $c, c', c'' \in C$. We want to prove that
\begin{align}
((b \otimes c)(b' \otimes c'))(b'' \otimes c'') =  (b \otimes c)((b' \otimes c')(b'' \otimes c'')).
\end{align}

We have
\begin{align}
(b \otimes c)(b' \otimes c') \\
= b \Psi(c \otimes b') c',
\end{align}
where $\Psi: C \otimes B \to B \otimes C$ is a braiding. $\Psi$ satisfies Hexagon identities:
\begin{align}
\Psi_{V,W \otimes Z} = \Psi_{V, Z} \circ \Psi_{V, W}, \\
\Psi_{V \otimes W, Z} = \Psi_{V, Z} \circ \Psi_{W, Z}.
\end{align}

We have
\begin{align}
((b \otimes c)(b' \otimes c'))(b'' \otimes c'') \\
= ( b \Psi(c \otimes b') c' )(b'' \otimes c'').
\end{align}
But how to multiply $( b \Psi(c \otimes b') c' )$ and $(b'' \otimes c'')$? How to prove
\begin{align}
((b \otimes c)(b' \otimes c'))(b'' \otimes c'') =  (b \otimes c)((b' \otimes c')(b'' \otimes c''))?
\end{align}
Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this prove we don't use Hexagon identities. The only thing we need is the functoriality of braiding - in our case it means that $\Psi$ commutes with multiplication :
$$\Psi(m\otimes\mathrm{id})=(\mathrm{id}\otimes m)(\Psi\otimes \mathrm{id})(\mathrm{id}\otimes \Psi)$$ 
We use it twice - in the first and the last step.

Remember that by definition $\Psi$ gives us **functorial** isomorphisms $\Psi_{W,V} :W\otimes V \rightarrow V\otimes W$, which, in particular, in case of algebra means commutation with multiplication and unit morphisms.
For details see for example S.Majid *Foundations of Quantum Group Theory*, Def. 9.2.1. and discussion below them.